# Numpy/Python: Array iteration without for-loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

So it's another n-dimensional array question:
I want to be able to compare each value in an n-dimensional arrays with its neighbours. For example if a is the array which is 2-dimensional i want to be able to check:

```
a[y][x]==a[y+1][x]
```

for all elements. So basically check all neighbours in all dimensions. Right now I'm doing it via:

```
for x in range(1,a.shape[0]-1):
   do.something(a[x])
```

The shape of the array is used, so that I don't run into an index out of range at the edges. So if I want to do something like this in n-D for all elements in the array, I do need n for-loops which seems to be untidy. Is there a way to do so via slicing? Something like a==a[:,-1,:] or am I understanding this fully wrong? And is there a way to tell a slice to stop at the end? Or would there be another idea of getting things to work in a totally other way? Masked arrays? 
Greets Joni

Comment: What do you do with the indices at the edges?

Comment: That's exactly the reason, why I'm using the for-loop until now. At the edge, there is no x+1 or z+1 so I'm iterating only until shape[0]-1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,4,5])
a == np.roll(a,1)
```

which returns

```
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool
```

You can specify an axis too for higher dimensions, though as others have said you'll need to handle the edges somehow as the values wrap around (as you can guess from the name)

For a fuller example in 2D:

```
# generate 2d data
a = np.array((np.random.rand(5,5)) * 10, dtype=np.uint8)

# check all neighbours
for ax in range(len(a.shape)):
    for i in [-1,1]:
        print a == np.roll(a, i, axis=ax)
```

Comment: so i guess one can shift in two directions in each axis and have some logical operators between them to get the desired behaviour

Comment: Yeah exactly, the rest depends on what result you're after

Comment: The problem is, that I can't use that one, to check only for special values (for example, only true if the values are zero) but I guess that one can be handled by comparing the array with the value and another logical operation (I'm going to figure out which ;) )

Comment: Well, the important line is `np.roll(a, i, axis=ax)` - what you compare it with, and what operations you use to combine the results from different "shifts" depends on the problem. If you've got more details then do post them

Comment: More details: I have a nontrivial distribution of ones and I want to check how many neighbours of them are ones as well and doing stuff on them depending on how many neighbours (in all dimensions) they have with the same value. For example: Delete all ones with exactly 5 neighbours, count all ones with 3 or more neighbours and so one. I have no really good idea to do that without for loops.

Comment: For documentation issues: I solved that dedicated problem that way:

    import scipy.ndimage as nd
    a=nd.binary_opening(a)

which by default deletes all elements with defined square connectivity of one. That version actually runs 30 times faster and takes care of the edge problem of my first post itself. So i guess I will open another question for the other nearest neighbour question. Thanks to everybody for their contribution.

Answer (score 2):

This might also be useful, this will compare each element to the following element, along axis=1. You can obviously adjust the axis or the distance. The trick is to make sure that both sides of the `==` operator have the same shape.

```
a[:, :-1, :] == a[:, 1:, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
np.diff(a) != 0
```

?

If you need the neighbours in the other axis, maybe diff the result of np.swapaxes(a) and merge the results together somehow ?

Comment: do you have an idea for a logical "or" with all values of an array?

Comment: @JonathanSchock: use something like `(a == 3. | a < 0)`.

Comment: @tiago: I don't get your answer in the context. What does "|" do?

Comment: @JonathanSchock: the `|` is a logical or. The result of `a == 3.` and `a < 0` is a boolean array. The `|` operation will return an array that is `True` when any of the conditions are `True`.