# Better way to compare neighboring cells in matrix

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, numpy, scipy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Numpy/Python: Array iteration without for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805286/numpy-python-array-iteration-without-for-loop)

Suppose I have a matrix of size 100x100 and I would like to compare each pixel to its direct neighbor (left, upper, right, lower) and then do some operations on the current matrix or a new one of the same size.
A sample code in Python/Numpy could look like the following:
(the comparison >0.5 has no meaning, I just want to give a working example for some operation while comparing the neighbors)

```
import numpy as np
my_matrix = np.random.rand(100,100)
new_matrix = np.array((100,100))
my_range = np.arange(1,99)
for i in my_range:
    for j in my_range:

        if my_matrix[i,j+1] > 0.5:
            new_matrix[i,j+1] = 1

        if my_matrix[i,j-1] > 0.5:
            new_matrix[i,j-1] = 1

        if my_matrix[i+1,j] > 0.5:
            new_matrix[i+1,j] = 1

        if my_matrix[i-1,j] > 0.5:
            new_matrix[i-1,j] = 1

        if my_matrix[i+1,j+1] > 0.5:
            new_matrix[i+1,j+1] = 1

        if my_matrix[i+1,j-1] > 0.5:
            new_matrix[i+1,j-1] = 1

        if my_matrix[i-1,j+1] > 0.5:
            new_matrix[i-1,j+1] = 1
```

This can get really nasty if I want to step into one neighboring cell and start from it to compare it to its neighbors ... Do you have some suggestions how this can be done in a more efficient manner? Is this even possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805286/numpy-python-array-iteration-without-for-loop/13805310

Comment: Maybe you should clarify what you want... just gessing, it sort of looks like you want to know which pixel with value 1 is surrounded by 8 pixels, all having 1. Is this it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you're aiming for with your code, which ignoring indexing issues at boundaries is equivalent to

```
new_matrix = my_matrix > 0.5
```

but you can do advanced versions of these calculation quickly with morphological operations:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import morphology

a = np.random.rand(5,5)
b = a > 0.5

element = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
result = morphology.binary_dilation(b, element) * 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look into morphological operations (never heard of this before). As I wrote in my updated post >0.5 should only be an example for some operations...

Comment: The wikipedia article and this site: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/dilate.htm are a good place to start. The "Exercise 1" at the bottom of the page shows the structuring element in my example.

Comment: I think I got it, however, it does not help me with the second problem. If a neighbor fulfills a specific condition I would like to start from this neighbor anew with the process...meaning the neighbors of this specific neighbors should be checked...

Comment: In that case, you should run the condition on the whole array to get out a binary result. Then extract the connected component that contain your starting point (equivalent to doing a flood fill), which you can do with: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html . This also allows you to specify your structuring element that defines how pixels can be connected.

Comment: I will look into that! Do you think it is also applicable for a "shortest path" algorithm based on a cost-surface matrix? This was for instance one application what I used the code above for.

Comment: Err, I don't think it'll help you much with that, but I also don't have time to try and explain my thoughts right now...

Answer (score 0):

The way to keep this from "getting nasty" is: Encapsulate the neighbor-checking code in a function. Then you can just call it with the coordinates of the neighbor when necessary.

If you need to keep track of which pairs you've checked, so that you don't keep the same ones, use some sort of memoization on top of that.

Comment: What's with the downvote? The OP is specifically concerned about chaining the checks. If someone doesn't think this answer is relevant, I'd like to know why. (And there's already a nice answer on how to bundle the checks, which the OP found insufficient for precisely this reason).

Comment: I also think your solution is suitable. I guess will have to write something like a combination of both solutions to make it work better..