# Parallel array manipulations in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I have a code in which I need to handle some big numpy arrays. For example I have a 3D array `A` and I need to construct another 3d array `B` using the elements of `A`. However all the elements of `B` are independent of each other. Example:

```
for i in np.arange(Nx):
  for j in np.arange(Ny):
   for k in np.arange(Nz):
       B[i][j][k] = A[i+1][j][k]*np.sqrt(A[i][j-1][k-1])
```

So it will speed up immensely if I can construct the `B` array parallely. What is the simplest way to do this in python?

I also have similar matrix operations like normalizing each row of a 2D array. Example

```
for i in np.arange(Nx):
   f[i,:] = f[i,:]/np.linalg.norm(f[i,:])
```

This will also speed up if it runs parallely for each row. How can it be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numpy/Python: Array iteration without for-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805286/numpy-python-array-iteration-without-for-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [Numpy's `roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) function. I think this is equivalent to your first block of code (though you need to decide what happens at the edges - `roll` "wraps around"):

```
B = np.roll(A,1,axis=0) * np.sqrt(np.roll(np.roll(A,-1,axis=1),-1,axis=2))
```

Another fairly horrible one-liner for your second case is:

```
f /= np.sqrt(np.sum(f**2, axis=1))[...,np.newaxis]
```

Explanation of this line:

We are first going to calculate the norm of each row. Let's

```
f = np.random.rand(5,6)
```

Square each element of `f`

```
f**2
```

Sum the squares along axis 1, which "flattens" out that axis.

```
np.sum(f**2, axis=1)
```

Take the square root of the sum of the squares.

```
np.sqrt(np.sum(f**2, axis=1))
```

We now have the norm of each row.

To divide each original row of `f` by this correctly we need to make use of the Numpy broadcasting rules to effectively add a dimension:

```
np.sqrt(np.sum(f**2, axis=1))[...,np.newaxis]
```

And finally we calculate our result

```
f /= np.sqrt(np.sum(f**2, axis=1))[...,np.newaxis]
```

Comment: In the actual code, the edges are well taken care of, but the construction of the `B` matrix is far more complicated, so the `numpy.roll` function makes things very messy and susceptible to errors. Isn't there a simple way to run different iterations of the for-loop independently?

Comment: Susceptible to errors in terms of programming errors or in terms of handling edges?

Comment: Programming errors. Also, I was looking for a generic way to parallelize iterations of for loops where each loop is independent.

Comment: I understand, but for me at least the generic way *is* to "line up" the elements with something like `roll`, maybe creating some intermediate arrays if it's getting messy. In terms of the full range of options to parallelize your code, you should take a look at [this](http://ianozsvald.com/2012/03/18/high-performance-python-1-from-pycon-2012-slides-video-src/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking good care of the edges, the standard way of going about your first vectorization would be something like this:

```
B = np.zeros(A.shape)
B[:-1, 1:, 1:] = A[1:, 1:, 1:] * np.sqrt(A[:-1, :-1, :-1])
```

You would then need to fill `B[-1, :, :]`, `B[:, 0, :]` and `B[:, :, 0]` with appropriate values.

Extending this to other indices should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

To perform parallel processing in `numpy`, you should look at [mpi4py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mpi4py). It's an MPI binding for Python. It allows distributed processing.