# How to Find the Neighbors of a Cell in an ndarray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I'm working with n-dimensional arrays in Python, and I want to find the "neighbors" (adjacent cells) of a given cell based on its coordinates. The issue is that I don't know the number of dimensions beforehand.

I attempted to use [`numpy.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13805310/2827555), but it seems unclear how to apply this method to multiple dimensions.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: `myarray.shape` holds information about the dimentionality of the array

Comment: @yurib I'm aware of that. What I meant was that I can't base the implementation on a set number of dimensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have an `(ndims,)` vector of indices specifying some point `p`, and you want an `(m, ndims)` array of indices corresponding to the locations of every adjacent element in the array (including diagonally adjacent elements).

Starting out with your indexing vector `p`, you want to offset each element by every possible combination of -1, 0 and +1. This can be done by using [`np.indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) to generate an `(m, ndims)` array of offsets, then adding these offsets to `p`.

You might want to exclude point `p` itself (i.e. where `offset == np.array([0, 0, ..., 0])`, and you may also need to exclude out-of-bounds indices.

```
import numpy as np

def get_neighbours(p, exclude_p=True, shape=None):

    ndim = len(p)

    # generate an (m, ndims) array containing all strings over the alphabet {0, 1, 2}:
    offset_idx = np.indices((3,) * ndim).reshape(ndim, -1).T

    # use these to index into np.array([-1, 0, 1]) to get offsets
    offsets = np.r_[-1, 0, 1].take(offset_idx)

    # optional: exclude offsets of 0, 0, ..., 0 (i.e. p itself)
    if exclude_p:
        offsets = offsets[np.any(offsets, 1)]

    neighbours = p + offsets    # apply offsets to p

    # optional: exclude out-of-bounds indices
    if shape is not None:
        valid = np.all((neighbours < np.array(shape)) & (neighbours >= 0), axis=1)
        neighbours = neighbours[valid]

    return neighbours
```

Here's a 2D example that's easy to visualize:

```
p = np.r_[4, 5]
shape = (6, 6)

neighbours = get_neighbours(p, shape=shape)

x = np.zeros(shape, int)
x[tuple(neighbours.T)] = 1
x[tuple(p)] = 2

print(x)
# [[0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 1]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 2]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 1]]
```

This will generalize to any dimensionality.

---

If you just want to be able to index the "neighbourhood" of `p` and you don't care about excluding `p` itself, a much simpler and faster option would be to use a tuple of `slice` objects:

```
idx = tuple(slice(pp - 1, pp + 2) for pp in p)
print(x[idx])
# [[1 1]
#  [1 2]
#  [1 1]]
```